# Why don't variables in TypeScript implicitly infer literal typing?

Tags: compiler, typescript

Given a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), for instance `1 | 2`, assigning a value to a variable that correctly corresponds to the literal type will fail.

```ts
interface SomeInterface {
    foo: (1 | 2);
}
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    foo = 1; // <- generates the following compiler error:
    /*
        Property 'foo' in type 'SomeClass' is not assignable to the same 
        property in base type 'SomeInterface'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2'.
    */
}
```

However, explicitly declaring the literal type will satisfy the compiler.

```ts
interface SomeInterface {
    foo: (1 | 2);
}
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    foo: (1 | 2) = 1; // <- no error
}
```

Type assertion may also be used:

```ts
foo = 1 as (1 | 2); // <- no error
// or
foo = <1 | 2>1; // <- no error
```

For primitive types, it should be trivial for the compiler to know that the value `1` is of type `(1 | 2)` (heck, even just of type `(1)`!). Is there a design reason why TypeScript's compiler does not implicitly infer literal types from literal values?

Comment: More generally, there comes a point at which the cost of precise language tunings exceeds the benefits, a phenomenon we call "diminishing returns."  Language design and feature implementation are expensive, companies that create programming languages do not have unlimited resources, and sometimes good enough is good enough.  In other words, there doesn't have to be a good reason for a particular language design choice.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm sorry if you think that the need to drill down the exact cause of this [documented issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570#issuecomment-296860943) is pedantic, but the purpose of downvoting is not for subjective dislike, but for malformed questions or factual errors. Your nebulous mention of diminishing returns is irrelevant to the topic, and your namecalling is inappropriate.

Comment: Why all the assumptions? I did not know know about the TypeScript defect before asking this question. @amon's explanation made me understand the root issue, which led me to find the GitHub issue, which I then relayed in the solution. Is there a problem with this process?

Comment: I doubt that the downvoters read your conversation with @amon before downvoting.  Those that did probably figured that you didn't do your homework before asking, a perfectly valid reason to downvote (hover your mouse over the downvote button).  But again, I'm still merely speculating.  At the end of the day, the only people that really know the answer to your question are the language designers themselves, and they're probably not here.

Comment: That's why I posted his comment in my answer
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @amon's comment:

> this behaviour indicates that the type checker does not inherit this info from the interface, but first type-checks the class (incl. type inference for foo) and then checks whether the class conforms to the interface. It does not conform because the type of a read-write variable must be invariant.

It looks like the actual issue here is that [classes do not properly infer the types of their members from interface(s) they implement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570#issuecomment-296860943). The issue is *not* casting. If it were, then `foo: (1 | 2) = 1` in the implementing `class` would not compile. The compiler *does* know that `1` is a valid value of type `1 | 2`, but the *default* type of `1` is `number`. Without the `class` knowing the type of `foo` by looking at the interface (which is really what it should be doing), `foo = 1` tries to type `foo` as a number, and at this moment the `interface` decides to do its job by disallowing compilation because `number` is not of type `1 | 2`... better late than never, I suppose.

Type assertion should almost never be used with literals. `foo = 3 as (1 | 2)` does not produce a compiler error, allowing an accidental typo to break an application, while `foo: (1 | 2) = 3;` does not compile, which in most cases, is desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's a question of using the info beforehand for inference, or afterwards for error-checking. Both make sense, depending on whether you value comfort or explicitness (*not* safety) more. It would be a different story if one tried to assign from a variable instead of interpreting a literal in the program.

Comment: Isn't `foo: (1 | 2) = 1` an *explicit cast?*  Nobody made the assertion that such a cast could not succeed. `foo = 3 as (1 | 2)` is not a compiler error because you've told the compiler to do the cast anyway, that you know what you are doing.  It's still an error, of course, but you've deferred the error to runtime.

Comment: No, `foo: (1 | 2) = 1;` is not a [cast](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). The value `1` is assignable to the primitive type `1 | 2`, just as it is assignable to type `number`.

Comment: @Deduplicator The question is "Why don't variables in TypeScript implicitly infer literal typing?" The answer is [this TypeScript behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570#issuecomment-296860943), and the workaround is to explicitly redeclare the property type in the class as defined in the interface. Casting is closely related, but not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a design reason why TypeScript's compiler does not implicitly infer literal types from literal values?

You can't do it in C# either:

```cs
SomeEnum s = 1; // Fails, even though one of the enum values corresponds to 1.

SomeEnum s = (SomeEnum)1; // succeeds.
```

Generally speaking, **implicit casting must not cause loss of information.**  Implicit casting from, say, `int` to `long` is allowed because `long` has a much greater range than `int`.

But if your programming language implicitly casts `1` to `1 | 2`, it takes a type (an `int`) that can be one of 4 billion possible values, and changes it to a type that can only be one of two possible values.  Such an implicit cast can easily fail at runtime, if the number you provided is out of range.

If, on the other hand, you explicitly cast to the enum type, you're essentially telling the compiler "Allow the cast; I know what I'm doing."

Comment: Your explanation makes sense for the type assertion, but what about having to redeclare the type to the same type that's already specified in the interface? It seems to me that if _casting_ is the issue, then `foo: (1 | 2) = 1` should still produce an error, but it doesn't. It's not like the compiler doesn't already know that `foo` is `(1 | 2)` — it already has that info from the interface. This behavior seems inconsistent. Is there some basic understanding here that I'm lacking?

Comment: @Jacob this behaviour indicates that the type checker does not inherit this info from the interface, but first type-checks the class (incl. type inference for `foo`) and then checks whether the class conforms to the interface. It does not conform because the type of a read-write variable must be invariant.

Comment: @amon "It does not conform because the type of a read-write variable must be invariant." I followed you up until this part. Could you explain this further?

Comment: @JacobStamm That's type theory speak for "the type is not allowed to change in subtypes". This follows from the Liskov Substitution Principle. For a writable variable, the subtype can widen the variable type, i.e. accept more values (contravariance). For a readable variable the subtype can narrow the variable type, i.e. promise a more specific type (covariance). A read-write variable must satisfy both these constraints, this is only possible if it doesn't change at all (invariance). In your example the type of foo is widened from an enum to all numbers.

Comment: @amon I see! Notwithstanding value assignment, simply redeclaring `foo` in the class as `foo: number;`, or even `foo: (1 | 2 | 3);`, produces the same compiler error. This is consistent with your explanation.

Comment: @JacobStamm: In the C# example, there is a difference between the _name_ of the enum and its _possible values_ (the two are linked by the enum definition that is required to exist). In your Typescript example, the enum's possible values doubles as its "type name". `foo: (1 | 2) = 1` is really just doing `foo: (MyEnumType) = 1` but since there is no custom name defined for this enum, you're forced to "name it" by repeating the definition.

Comment: @JacobStamm: `it should be trivial for the compiler to know that the value 1 is of type (1 | 2)` That is the case in your example, where the value is hardcoded. But what if `myNumber` is an int whose value I've parsed from an external source? I have no idea what value I'm getting, whether it is 1, 2, or 15264.

Comment: @amon Would you make your explanation its own answer? If my understanding is correct, this topic has nothing to do with implicit casting and everything to do with type invariance. If casting were the issue, then `foo: (1 | 2) = 1;` would not work, but would require `foo: (1 | 2) = 1 as (1 | 2);` or, without the redundant type declaration, `foo = 1 as `(1 | 2);` Moreover, the fact that `foo: (1 | 2) = 3;` produces a compiler error while `foo = 3 as (1 | 2)` does not means that latter method is really not desired if those literal types are to have any design-time meaning

Comment: @JacobStamm Sorry I don't have the time for writing a proper answer. And I don't actually know anything about TypeScript, I'm afraid. Now that you understand what's going on you could answer your own question!

Comment: @amon Done Please upvote the question and answer if you can. Despite the relevance and proper protocol of this question, apparently a couple of people have decided they don't like the topic.